# Create vertical gradient texture programmatically in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

So I have these scene in SceneKit where I programmatically create a bunch of objects each of different heights. Most of them are simple boxes, but some of them are extruded paths.

I need to be able to add a simple material color for them such that the color goes from a darker value to a lighter one from bottom to top.

I've been trying to achieve this by creating a material with a texture of a gradient image programmatically created from a `CAGradientLayer`. This "almost" works. The problem with this approach is that ALL faces of an object will get same effect which is not what I want. The top and bottom surfaces of objects should be of solid colors - the light color on top surface and the light one at the bottom.

I've been playing with shaders also but the result is a gradient which is relative to the screen instead of my object thus rendering my 3D object as 2D.

Here's how I create a simple **solid color** box for example:

```
func createBox(with bounds: CGRect, and height: CGFloat) {
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
        material.metalness.contents = 0.2
        material.roughness.contents = 0.5
    }

    let geometry = SCNBox(width: bounds.size.width, height: height, length: bounds.size.height, chamferRadius: 0.0)
    geometry.materials = [material]
    geometry.chamferRadius = 0.02

    let node = NKNode(geometry: geometry)
}
```

Now, since a box has 6 different geometry elements by default I can choose to create a material which has it's contents set to a gradient image and then add said material 6 times in the `materials` array of the `geometry`. This allows me to set a material for each face individually, like so:

```
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "gradient-test")
geometry.materials = [material, material, material, material, material, material]
```

With this I can have 3 different materials (sides, top, bottom) and by trial and error add them in the correct order in the `materials` array. That will translate into this:

```
let sideMaterial = SCNMaterial()
sideMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "gradient")

let topMaterial = SCNMaterial()
topMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white

let bottomMaterial = SCNMaterial()
bottomMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.black

// The order is side, side, side, side, top, bottom
geometry.materials = [sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, sideMaterial, topMaterial, bottomMaterial]
```

But my problem then appears when my object is **not** a simple box but an extruded path. Here's how those get created:

```
func createFromPath(_ path: UIBezierPath, with height: CGFloat) {
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
        material.metalness.contents = 0.2
        material.roughness.contents = 0.5
    }
    material.isDoubleSided = true

    let geometry = SCNShape(path: path, extrusionDepth: height)
    geometry.materials = [material]
    geometry.chamferRadius = 0.02
}
```

As you can see, the simple **solid color** is easy. But applying the same logic to add the gradient texture on the side is not working anymore since my path can have an undefined numbers of faces. And to be honest I even think that a geometry created like that is not split into multiple "elements" like the simple box is.

So, any idea how I can achieve what I want?

### Update

---

Here's a really basic example of what I would like to achieve. As you can see, the 3D "buildings" in this map have a subtle bottom to top gradient.

[image]

Comment: Can you show any imagery that's indicative of the effect you're trying to achieve? I might know a shortcut.

Comment: See my update, please...

Comment: argh, ok. This is normally done by lighting and baking. I'll have to write something a bit longish to explain it. If you have some time, search for "ambient occlusion" on google, that's a more thorough approach, but there are lighter ways to do this... excuse the pun.

Comment: Hm... Anything for me @Confused?

Comment: How did you get on with Ambient Occlusion and learning about lighting?

Comment: Well, I did read about it. I even found some answer of yours here on SO about it. But that didn't helped much. I still don't know how to texture my objects :(

Comment: I _think_ the message is: do not use textures but play with light position plus material settings (occlusion and such) to achieve your requirements.

Comment: Try to stop thinking about how to texture your objects, and instead focus on lighting solutions.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a solution to this?